# can we retrieve the data by sending id field as json object using POST method in django rest framework

Tags: django

```
GET : http://127.0.0.1:8000/r/

{
    "count": 5,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/r/1/",
            "name": "India",
            "code": 91
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/r/3/",
            "name": "us",
            "code": 10,
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/r/4/",
            "name": "pak",
            "code": 9
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/r/5/",
            "name": "kansas",
            "code": 44
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/r/6/",
            "name": "kanada",
            "code": 123
        }
}
```

I know that , suppose I can get  "name": "us", "code": 10 based on it's "id": 2 by specifying the id in the URL like http://127.0.0.1:8000/r/2,
By using GET method,
but I want to retrive "name": "us", "code": 10 based on it's "id": 2 by sending it(means 'id') as json object using 'POST' method.

Comment: POST is for creating a new item, not for retrieve data on an existing item.

Comment: Yes you can send id in json object but it would be better if you use GET request as it only retrieves data from DB

Comment: @nishant : how can we send id in json object using postman, if we use GET request. please  tell me if you know.

Comment: in get request you can send json object as string in query parameter. with query parameter name - json

Comment: like this : http://jsoneditoronline.org/?json={%22name%22:%22John%22,%22age%22:32}